# Set giving extra element

Tags: c++

I'm doing some rather simple code with `set`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

void printSol(map<string, string> parelles, const set<string>& sols) {
    cout << "COUPLES:" << endl;
    for (auto& x : parelles) {
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
        parelles.erase(x.second);
    }
    cout << "ALONE:" << endl;
        for (auto x : sols) {
            cout << x << endl;
    }
    cout << "----------" << endl;
}

int main() {
    map<string, string> parelles;
    set<string> sols;
    string inst, nom1, nom2;
    while (cin >> inst) {
        if (inst == "liats") {
            cin >> nom1 >> nom2;
            sols.erase(nom1);
            sols.erase(nom2);
            sols.insert(parelles[nom1]);
            sols.insert(parelles[nom2]);
            parelles.erase(parelles[nom1]);
            parelles.erase(parelles[nom2]);
            parelles[nom1] = nom2;
            parelles[nom2] = nom1;
        }
        else if (inst == "info") {
            printSol(parelles, sols);
        }
    }

}
```

For the input:

```
liats gerard shakira
liats sara iker
liats gerard sara
liats iker cristiano
info
```

It prints

```
COUPLES:
cristiano iker
gerard sara
ALONE:

shakira
----------
```

but should print

```
COUPLES:
cristiano iker
gerard sara
ALONE:
shakira
----------
```

But there is an extra `endl` after `ALONE`. I checked the size of the `set` and it's 2, and I don't really know what's going on. It seems like `x` has the null `string`.
Can someone point out in the right direction?

Comment: When you do `sols.insert(parelles[nom1]);` in the first iteration of the loop in `main`, the map `parelles` is empty, and so this creates a default string `""` as the value for the key `nom1`, which you insert, but then never remove from `sols`.

Comment: Also, you're erasing elements while you iterate over `parelles`. That can lead to undefined behavior if you erase the element you're currently on, as it invalidates the iterator. This can happen if you enter `liats a a` followed by `info` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map::operator[]` strikes again. This operator inserts a value-initialized element if the key doesn't exist in the map. For string, this means it will insert an empty string. Here's a fix:

```
// sols.insert(parelles[nom1]);
// sols.insert(parelles[nom2]); 

auto it = parelles.find(nom1);
if (it != parelles.end()) sols.insert(it->second);
it = parelles.find(nom2);
if (it != parelles.end()) sols.insert(it->second);
```